# Displaying object with multiple properties in Listview

Tags: xamarin

I have class which returns a list

```
class Book
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string Year { get; set; }

    public static List<Book> GetList()
    {
        var bookList = new List<Book>();
        bookList.Add(new Book
        {
            Author = "Robin Cook",
            Title = "Vector",
            Year = "1999"

        });
        bookList.Add(new Book
        {
            Author = "J.K. Rowling",
            Title = "Harry Potter and Prisoner of Azkaban",
            Year = "1999"
        });
        bookList.Add(new Book
        {
            Author = "George R.R. Martin",
            Title = "A Dance with Dragons",
            Year = "2011"
        });

        return bookList;
    }
}
```

I would like the page to have a listview with each cell containing triplet Author - Title - Year, that is,

```
 Robin Cook - Vector - 1999
 ...
```

In XAML code behind, I have

```
 var listView = new ListView();
 listView.ItemsSource = Book.GetList();

 var cellTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
 {
      var textCell = new TextCell();
      var titleLabel = new Label();
      var authorLabel = new Label();
      var yearLabel = new Label();

      titleLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Title");
      authorLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Author");
      yearLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Year");
      textCell.Text = titleLabel.Text + " - " + authorLabel.Text + " - " + yearLabel;

  return textCell;
 });

 listView.ItemTemplate = cellTemplate;
 Content = listView;
```

All I see are empty cells with hyphens. Can you please tell what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a read-only property in your Model

```
public string DisplayText {
  get {
    return $"{Title} - {Author} - {Year}";
  }
}
```

and bind to it

```
var cellTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
 {
      var textCell = new TextCell();
      textCell.SetBinding(TextCell.TextProperty, "DisplayText")

  return textCell;
 });
```

Or, you could create a ViewCell containing three separate labels for each value you want do display

```
var cellTemplate = new DataTemplate(() => 
{
  var viewCell = new ViewCell();
  var titleLabel = new Label();
  var authorLabel = new Label();
  var yearLabel = new Label();

  titleLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Title");
  authorLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Author");
  yearLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Year");

  StackLayout stack = new StackLayout();
  stack.Children.Add(titleLabel);
  stack.Children.Add(authorLabel);
  stack.Children.Add(yearLabel);

  viewCell.Content = stack;

  return viewCell;
});
```

Comment: HI, thank you. Your solution works. But can you please comment on why doesn't mine work? Also, if you could elaborate on your last line - Create ViewCell containing three separate labels - a code snippet would help. Thank you!

Comment: I expanded my example for the ViewCell alternative.  Frankly, your original solution was just garbage.  You were creating Labels, binding them, then using their values to build up a string, and then throwing away the Labels you just created.  This is not how data binding works.

Comment: Thank you. That was a helpful opinion.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, there should be some binding context between the xaml components and the Book class.

If you want to implement in the way you implemented it, you could do the following:

```
var cellTemplate = new DataTemplate(()=>
{
   var textCell = new TextCell();
            if(i<Book.GetList().Count)
            {
                var titleLabel = new Label();
                var authorLabel = new Label();
                var yearLabel = new Label();

                titleLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Title");
                titleLabel.BindingContext = new { Title = Book.GetList()[i].Title };
                authorLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Author");
                authorLabel.BindingContext = new { Author = Book.GetList()[i].Author };
                yearLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Year");
                yearLabel.BindingContext = new { Year = Book.GetList()[i].Year };
                textCell.Text = titleLabel.Text + " - " + authorLabel.Text + " - " + yearLabel;
                i++;
            }

            return textCell;
}
```

Comment: What is i here?

Comment: its an integer which acts as a counter and is to be declared outside of  var cellTemplate = new DataTemplate(()=>